# How to use String.prototype.toUpperCase with const assertions in TS?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying get uppercase version of a value in TS:

```
const directions = ['asc', 'desc'] as const

type Directions = typeof directions[number]

const [asc, desc] = directions

const order: Record<string, Uppercase<Directions>> = {
  a: asc.toUpperCase(),  // <- I need the type of this value to be 'ASC'
  d: desc.toUpperCase(), // <- I need the type of this value to be 'DESC'
}
```

But because `String.prototype.toUppercase` returns `string` following error is thrown:

```
Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"ASC" | "DESC"'.
```

I found two solutions so far, but neither one of them are preferable:

*1: use Type Assertion (`as`):*

```
const order: Record<string, Uppercase<Directions>> = {
  a: asc.toUpperCase() as Uppercase<Directions>,
  d: desc.toUpperCase() as Uppercase<Directions>,
}
```

**Con:** Type safety is not guaranteed - `order` can be changed to something like

```
const order: Record<string, Uppercase<Directions>> = {
  a: ''.toUpperCase() as Uppercase<Directions>,
  d: ''.toUpperCase() as Uppercase<Directions>,
}
```

and TS won't complain.

*2: create custom `toUpperCase` function with different signature*

```
const toUpperCase = <T extends string>(input: T): Uppercase<T> => input.toUpperCase() as Uppercase<T>

const order: Record<string, Uppercase<Directions>> = {
    a: toUpperCase(asc),
    d: toUpperCase(desc),
}
```

**Con:** Developers have to be taught that they shouldn't use the built in function and it might confuse junior developers on whether they should use the built in method or the custom one.

Is there a type safe solution while using the native `String.prototype.toUppercase` method?

Answer (score 1):

As you note, currently the type checker does not understand that, for example, `"asc".toUpperCase()` will produce a value of [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) `"ASC"`.  There is a suggestion at [microsoft/TypeScript#44268](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/44268) that the [typings](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/66fbf058ece7882f2a964aeeda81bc352e4a6329/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L494-L500) for [the `toUpperCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toUpperCase)  and [the `toLowerCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase) methods of `string` values be updated so that they return the appropiate [intrinsic string manipulation types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html#intrinsic-string-manipulation-types).  Currently it's listed as "awaiting more feedback", so if you want to see this happen you might want to give it a .  For now it's not part of the language.

---

Luckily, if you want to get this behavior now, you can use [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) to add appropriate call signatures to [the `String` interface](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/66fbf058ece7882f2a964aeeda81bc352e4a6329/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L402).  It looks like this:

```
// declare global { 
    interface String {
        toUpperCase<T extends string>(this: T): Uppercase<T>;
        toLowerCase<T extends string>(this: T): Lowercase<T>;
    }
// }
```

(If you are writing your code inside a [module](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html) then you need to use [global augmentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#global-augmentation) via `declare global` in order to merge the call signatures into the global `String` interface and not a module-local interface of the same name.)

The call signatures use a [`this` parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#this-parameters) of a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type to access the string literal type of the string on which you call the methods.  Otherwise you'd get `Uppercase<string>` and/or `Lowercase<string>` which isn't specific enough for you (in TS4.7 and below this is just `string`, while in TS4.8 and above these types are more specific than `string` and refer to "uppercase strings" and "lowercase strings", as implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#47050](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47050). But neither of these are what you want for `"asc".toUpperCase()`).

---

Let's test it out:

```
const order = {
    a: asc.toUpperCase(),
    d: desc.toUpperCase(),
}
/* const order: {
    a: "ASC";
    d: "DESC";
} */

const obj = {
    ASC: 123,
    DESC: "321"
}
obj[order.a].toFixed(2); // okay
obj[order.d].toLowerCase(); // okay
```

Looks good.  The compiler knows that `order.a` is `"ASC"` and `order.d` is `"DESC"`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.2#code/PTAEBMFMGMBsEMBOlQHNYHsBG9agN6gCwAUKOaAJYB2ALpIgGbzQoDKtiNqBpF-oWhgCqAB1EMAwvADOkADwAVUJAAe9auBmgZnbgD4AFLQAWlGQC5QigJRWxExNFkLF+gNx8B5IQBkMAO5SLkoq6pCa2rpc1KhGpuZWtlb+QU4hbp5kFAC+pCCgeSSk0BjUuhCUyNC0lGXaALygANoA5LLQrQA0oK1QMp0AuqCyoKXltCX1tC0dPf3Qw03gVTC19aRTE6AYiFCIoE34XuTwVh0AdEIOwXKGNl0nEFYLVyLit5D3jyRFwABUY2mOz2DCsx2ypysACIAIJsSTQrL8cAwgAiAFEEUjSDlQP9gJsSOMKtgAFaHXiQ0DwyRWACMACYAMw-fiYhEw5mM+nQ3FE8nNXb7C7wQZvABilFUkHAhkZNncoAKGAA1vAAJ6kQXChgXcDivyBT73JUq9Va4pWoA)